# Parse cloudwatch logs using filter patterns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this line of lambda function log   in cloudwatch that I receive by mail :

```
 /aws/lambda/sns-function | 2017/01/10/[$LATEST]425d9138c8d54ab57l0766ba74fdfd4p | 2017-01-10T00:04:30.734Z | 2017-01-10 00:04:30,734 :: ERROR :: error creating /tmp/tmpkRWp3S_20170110/file20170115.tar.gz: Command `['/bin/tar', '--create', '-z', '--file', u'/tmp/tmpkRWp3S_20170110/file20170115.tar.gz', '--', './']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

As explained in this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) I want to put filter patterns to get only the important data. For me, I want to get the date only once because in the line above, I have twice this information: `2017-01-10T00:04:30.734Z`
I tried to use a pattern like this :

```
[...,timestamp,level,message=*ERROR*,...]
```

but I got this error:

```
2017-01-17 10:45:58,091 :: ERROR :: logGroup: '/aws/lambda/sns-function' - logStream: 'None'
2017-01-17 10:45:58,091 :: ERROR :: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the FilterLogEvents operation: Duplicate field '...'
```

How can I parse the log to get the date once ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metric filters help you search for and match terms, phrases, or values in your log events. They **do not remove** values from the log event (the *timestamp* in your case). You could modify your script to exclude the *timestamp* from the output (since it is already included).

Also, you're using a metric filter for space-delimited log events. Your delimiter seems to be `::`, which wouldn't work in this case. The metric filter will interpret this as a single field. If you want to use this metric filter, you can enclose each field in square brackets `[]` or two double quotes `""`.

For example, you can use this pattern `[timestamp, result=ERROR, message, exit_status=*1*]` for the following log event:

```
[2017-01-10 00:04:30,734] [ERROR] "error creating /tmp/tmpkRWp3S_20170110/file20170115.tar.gz: Command `['/bin/tar', '--create', '-z', '--file', u'/tmp/tmpkRWp3S_20170110/file20170115.tar.gz', '--', './']' returned non-zero" "exit status 1"
```

**NOTE**: The reason for the error is that ellipsis `…` should occur only once in the pattern.

Comment: thank you, how can I display each field in the `event['message'] `  in python delimited by "|" ?

Comment: It's better to post a new question for that (including your code snippet), and tag it for python :)

Comment: Alright. Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697901/format-the-message-of-cloudwatch-logs